# Naudio: how to properly remove 1 out of several sounds played by an AsioOut without stopping all other sounds?

Tags: naudio, asio

I am using `AsioOut` because need to minimize latency as much as possible. Since I can only run 1 AsioOut at a time, I am using a `MixingWaveProvider32` to play back multiple sounds at the same time. The problem I am running into is that I don't know how to properly remove 1 sound without pausing all the others.

I can easily add a new `IWaveProvider` (`AudioFileReader` in my case) to the `MixingWaveProvider32` by simply adding it as an input stream, but if I try to remove it the same way the audio starts glitching (I think it's looping the last available buffer). I can prevent this by stopping the `AsioOut` before swapping the sound, but this brings 2 problems:

1. all other sounds also get stopped
2. if the sound I am trying to remove already finished on it's own then I get softlocked on `AsioOut.Stop()` (the method never finishes).

How do I properly remove 1 sound without running into these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself: By running all sounds through a `WaveChannel32` before putting them in the `MixingWaveProvider32` I can add and remove the sounds at any time without stopping the `AsioOut` without getting any audio glitches.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in `MixingWaveProvider32` due to the combination of `WaveBuffer` and `Array.Clear` which can fail to clear enough of the buffer resulting in the glitching sound you describe.

I suggest you try with `MixingSampleProvider` instead, which is the successor to `MixingWaveProvider32`

Comment: Tried using `MixingSampleProvider` instead, it has the same problems. Removing an input without stopping causes the audio to glitch and stopping after the music already finished results in a softlock.